# How to obtain the result of a select distinct as an entity list instead of tuples

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I'm writing a JSF application which lets the user select a list of documents from a list of folders where the user clicks the specific folder link to see the list of documents related to the selected folder.

After trying conventional ORM methods, I tried to define the following result class:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<ProjectDocs> findAllFolders(int projectid) {
    final String SQLCOMMAND
            = "SELECT DISTINCT d.classification, d.fk_projectdoc_id " + "FROM "
            + ProjectDocs.class.getSimpleName() + " d "
            + " WHERE d.fk_projectdoc_id = ?1";

    Query query = em.createQuery(SQLCOMMAND);
    query.setParameter(1, projectid);
    try {
      //  ListDataModel<ProjectDocs> lresults = new ListDataModel<ProjectDocs>(query.getResultList());
  List<ProjectDocs> lresults = query.getResultList();
        return lresults;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("FAILED", ex);
    }
}
```

My managed bean class is:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{projBB}")
// @Model

private ProjectsBB projectBean;

 public String selectFolders() {

    projects = projectBean.getProjectList().getRowData();
    projectid = projects.getProjectid();
    projects.setProjectid(projectid);
    listModel = (ListDataModel<ProjectDocs>) getFolderBaseModel();
    return "ProDocsFolderList";

}


   public DataModel<ProjectDocs> getFolderBaseModel() {

    /* Check cache */
    if (this.folderBaseModel == null) {
        this.folderBaseModel= buildFolderListModel(this.projectid);
    }
    return this.folderBaseModel;
}

public DataModel<ProjectDocs> buildFolderListModel(int projectid) {
    List<ProjectDocs> folderList = proDocs.findFolderList(projectid);
    DataModel<ProjectDocs> model = new ListDataModel<ProjectDocs>(folderList);
    return model;
}
```

The stack:

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "classification"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.toInteger(ArrayELResolver.java:378)
at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:198)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)....
```

I'm almost sure that this is caused by the use of explicit Select statements in my DAO class (where I'm selecting specific entity fields instead of the whole entiy), so that the results are returned as an array.

I would like to know 1) What the appropriate result class should look like? 2) Do I need to include a custom conversion class in addition or instead of the defined result class?

UPDATE:

I can't use the whole ProjectDocs entity because this would simply produce a list of documents with the folder name next to each document. I want to see ONLY DISTINCT list of folders so I need to explicitly SELECT classification and projectid in the SELECT statement

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you want the List so simply query for ProjectDocs not for their fields:

```
String SQLCOMMAND
            = "SELECT DISTINCT d FROM "
            + ProjectDocs.class.getSimpleName() + " d "
            + " WHERE d.fk_projectdoc_id = ?1";
```

Then the q`uery.getResultList()` will return list of matching ProjectDocs, and you should probably use the typed query so you dont need to cast:

```
TypedQuery<ProjectDocs> query = em.createQuery(SQLCOMMAND,ProjectDocs.class);
```

You can then access the classification field of the ProjectDosc on your JSF site.

With your current sql as you noticed you are asking just for two fields, so the results is Object[] with first entry matching type of classification second the id (long?).

If you want you can define a class that has only those two properrties and use it as the wrapper around your result, but typically you would just use the whole ProjectDocs bean.

```
public class Classification {
    String classification;
    long id;
    public Classification (String classification,long id) {
        this.Classification = classification;
        this.id = id;
    }
} 

String SQLCOMMAND
            = "SELECT new full.package.path.to.Classification( d.classification, d.fk_projectdoc_id) " + "FROM "
            + ProjectDocs.class.getSimpleName() + " d "
            + " WHERE d.fk_projectdoc_id = ?1";
```

Comment: in the sql command `select new full.package.path.to.your.WrapperClass( d.classification, d.fk_projectdoc_id) ...` as in my answer (though I forgot to include the whole path). You keep the ProjectDocs.class.getSimpleName() in the FROM clause as it is.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. I think wrapper class is what I need. I just want to clarify a couple of things before I apply this. As the update to my question shows, I can't use the whole ProjectDocs entity in the SELECT statement. So, how can I correctly use the wrapper class that you mention? In your above example the classification class is not mentioned in the SQLCOMMAND. I just include the wrapper class inside the ORM / DAO class?

Comment: it is mentioned in the `SELECT new path.to.Classification`. It is enough for jpa to pick it up. You can also use the Classification class as type parameter for the TypedQuery, but it still need to be part of the SELECT new ... sql.

Comment: The logic of your answer makes perfect sense, but I'm getting "javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.manaar.beans.module.content.docs.Classification' does not have the property 'classification'. Does this class need to be some type of managed bean?

Comment: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException this sounds like expression language exception not the persistence one, so it happens after it had been retrieved (check the whole stack). Does your wrapper class has Classification public field classification that you are trying to access, maybe you misspelled.

Comment: I checked the whole stack and for sure this is an EL exception. I'm going to mark your answer and upvote, but I still need to figure out how to get the EL pick up the property. I checked for spelling. I think the problem is that the query is picked up by the main managed bean in the JSF page  and the property is in a separate wrapper class (which is not a bean) so I need to figure out how to connect the wrapper, bean and EL/JSF page. Would appreciate any suggestions you have?

Comment: I am sorry I don't used JSF. But it sound weird. Make sure class is public and so does its fields or getters (maybe you miss the getter), in the context of JSF lifecycle maybe it has to be marked as serializable.

Comment: The getter was mispelled! It works PERFECTLY thank you very much!!